# How to get the marginal density function of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, density-function, marginal-probability

I am unsure how to get the marginal probability density function if the two random variables are dependent.

In general for given $f_{XY}(x,y)$ we get $$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy\tag1$$and $$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx\tag2$$
However I am unsure what happens if e.g. $x$ depends on $y$. Consider this example
$$ f_{XY}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
x+y& \text{ for } y\geq x\geq0, y\geq0  \\
0 & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases} $$
Then we get
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(x+y)dx = \frac{x^{2}}{2}+xy$$
but what will I get for $f_{X}(x)$ ?

Edit: To clarify this question, would the "easiest" solution
$$f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{y}(x+y)dy $$
be a valid solution?

Comment: $f_{XY}$ is  not a valid density function . It does not integrate to $1$.

Comment: I just invented that function for this example. A proper density function would go way beyond the point I am trying to clarify. Therefore just ignore the fact it doesnt integrate to 1

Comment: @youneedtoread1 : I amendend you "invented" example with one that works...you can use mine to understand the integral bounds....I enclosed also an hint

Comment: You will get $\infty$ for one of the marginals. You cannot just cook up some function  and call it  a density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example

$$ f_{XY}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
2(x+y)& \text{ for } 1\geq y\geq x\geq0 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases} $$

this is similar to yours but now $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is a nice density...

to obtain the marginals let's focus on the ${X,Y}$ domain

and consider that  the rv $X$ takes values in $(0;y)$

$$\underbrace{0<x<y}_{\text{X-integration bounds}}<1$$

while the rv $Y$ takes values in $(x;1)$

$$0<\underbrace{x<y<1}_{\text{Y-integration bounds}}$$

---

thus to calculate the marginals you can do

$$f_X(x)=\int_x^1 f(x,y)dy$$

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^y f(x,y)dx$$

Comment: This is exactly what I don't understand. Naively I would just try to calculate 
$\int_{0}^{y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy = f_X(x)$

Comment: @youneedtoread1 : That's not correct! I added some detail. Look at the support! all the information you need are written there!

Comment: So for this one
$f_X(x) = 3y^2$ and $f_Y(y) = -3x^2+2x+1$ ?

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now!